# Formally unramified morphisms and open diagonals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, ramification

Let $R\to S$ be a commutative unital $R$-algebra with dual arrow $X\to Y$. If I understand correctly, an open diagonal $\Delta_{X/Y}:X\to X\times _YX$ always implies $X\to Y$ is formally unramified, and the converse holds if $X\to Y$ is of finite type. Since everything is local it seems the same implications are valid for schemes (perhaps replacing 'finite type' with 'locally finite type').

For any continuous map between topological spaces, local injectivity is equivalent to having an open diagonal.

Thus it seems the naive description of non-ramification - local injectivity - is generally stronger than the one using nilpotents and particularly tangent vectors. In differential geometry the opposite is true by virtue of the local form of smooth immersions of smooth manifolds. The only obstruction is locally constant rank.

**Questions.**

1. What are some geometric examples of formally unramified morphisms of (affine) schemes with non-open diagonal? What is the intuition?
2. Is being essentially of finite type enough? That is, if $X\to Y$ is formally unramified and essentially of finite type, will $\Delta_{X/Y}$ be open (in the affine case)?